# How To Receive Data From Web socket's Using Python

Tags: javascript, python, sockets, websocket

So basically I want to create a Websocket server using Python, on my last question about this I said I didn't want to use external libraries, but that wasn't received very well. So how can you do it using external libraries? I have already figured out the Websocket send using Javascript, but I need a Python Websocket server. So can someone give me a working example with Python 3.6?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the following comes from https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html ... which was the second link i think i found when i googled "python3 websockets"

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import asyncio
import websockets

async def hello(websocket, path):
    name = await websocket.recv()
    print("< {}".format(name))

    greeting = "Hello {}!".format(name)
    await websocket.send(greeting)
    print("> {}".format(greeting))

start_server = websockets.serve(hello, 'localhost', 8765)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Comment: Module 'websockets' not found? Python 3.6.1

Comment: .... https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html#installation